# Do I need to call both unbindService and stopService for Android services?

Tags: android, serviceconnection

In my Android app, I call both `startService` and `bindService`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() { ... }

startService(intent)
bindService(intent, conn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Later, I attempt to both `unbindService and`stopService`:

```
unbindService(conn);
stopService(intent);
```

However, I get an exception on the call to `unbindService`.  If I remove this call, the app seems to run properly through the `stopService` call.

Am I doing something wrong?  I thought a `bindService` call had to be associated with an `unbindService` call, and a `startService` call had to be associated with a `stopService` call.  This doesn't seem to be the case here, though.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I ran into the same thing, and commented out the unbindService(conn) for myself. Seems to work okay, but just like you, my gut says something in the background wouldn't like it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Android documentation for stopService() states:

> Note that if a stopped service still has ServiceConnection objects bound to it with the BIND_AUTO_CREATE set, it will not be destroyed until all of these bindings are removed. See the Service documentation for more details on a service's lifecycle.

So calling `stopService()` first followed by `unbindService()` should work (it's working for me).

Comment: Ahh, so it sounds like my ordering of `unbindService` and `stopService` were backwards, I see.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! I had BIND_AUTO_CREATE used and unbindService() helped to solve the problem with ServiceConnection leak.

Comment: @Matt Huggins so you guys mean to unbind first and then stop is it?

Comment: Calling stopService first then unbindService works for me.

Comment: `the service runs until the service stops itself with stopSelf() or another component calls stopService(), regardless of whether it is bound to any clients.` https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Lifecycle

Answer (score 8):

A gotcha that I hit with this:

Ensure you call unbindService on the same context that you called bindService. In my case, I was doing the following to bind it:

```
Context c = getApplicationContext();
c.bindService(...);
```

Then to unbind it, just:

```
unbindService(...);
```

Making sure both bind and unbind used the same context solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) it depends what you want to achieve and how you bind the service. If you want to have a long time reference to the service, it is better to use bindService than startService. If in the bindService method, the flag BIND_AUTO_CREATE is used, then you don't have to call startService, because the service starts itself when necessary.

If you call unBind service, then you assoication to the service is deleted. You dont' have to explicitly stop the service but you can. But it's importatnt to note, that if you call unBind(), then the service is allowed to stop at any time.

Comment: Thanks, but I've been there, and it's not clear if I need to both unbind and stop the service if I manually started it before binding to it with the BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag.

Comment: `But it's importatnt to note, that if you call unBind(), then the service is allowed to stop at any time.` — No, if it was started, it will not stop until a call to `stopSelf` or `stopService`: `the service runs until the service stops itself with stopSelf() or another component calls stopService(), regardless of whether it is bound to any clients.` https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question directly, it is "okay" to not call unbindservice BUT it is not recommended. What happens is if your service is not a foreground service, android system may kills it to free up memory. And if there is still some component bounded to it, but you haven't called unbind, it gets unbound by the android system.

See android documentation here

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

> If your client is still bound to a service when your app destroys the
>   client, destruction causes the client to unbind. It is better practice
>   to unbind the client as soon as it is done interacting with the
>   service. Doing so allows the idle service to shut down. For more
>   information about appropriate times to bind and unbind, see Additional
>   notes.

Comment: The cited documentation seems to be about cases where the service won't be stopped when possible (because it isn't needed), but if you stop the service, it doesn't seem so clear anymore if you should and can unbind, too.

Comment: `the service runs until the service stops itself with stopSelf() or another component calls stopService(), regardless of whether it is bound to any clients.` https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Lifecycle